# How to interpret type I, type II, and type III ANOVA and MANOVA?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, manova, sums-of-squares

My primary question is how to interpret the output (coefficients, F, P) when conducting a Type I (sequential) ANOVA?

My specific research problem is a bit more complex, so I will break my example into parts. First, if I am interested in the effect of spider density (X1) on say plant growth (Y1) and I planted seedlings in enclosures and manipulated spider density, then I can analyze the data with a simple ANOVA or linear regression. Then it wouldn't matter if I used Type I, II, or III Sum of Squares (SS) for my ANOVA. In my case, I have 4 replicates of 5 density levels, so I can use density as a factor or as a continuous variable. In this case, I prefer to interpret it as a continuous independent (predictor) variable. In R I might run the following:

```
lm1 <- lm(y1 ~ density, data = Ena)
summary(lm1)
anova(lm1)
```

Running the anova function will make sense for comparison later hopefully, so please ignore the oddness of it here. The output is:

```
Response: y1
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
density    1 0.48357 0.48357  3.4279 0.08058 .
Residuals 18 2.53920 0.14107
```

Now, let's say I suspect that the starting level of inorganic nitrogen in the soil, which I couldn't control, may have also significantly affected the plant growth. I'm not particularly interested in this effect but would like to potentially account for the variation it causes. Really, my primary interest is in the effects of spider density (hypothesis: increased spider density causes increased plant growth - presumably through reduction of herbivorous insects but I'm only testing the effect not the mechanism). I could add the effect of inorganic N to my analysis.

For the sake of my question, let's pretend that I test the interaction density*inorganicN and it's non-significant so I remove it from the analysis and run the following main effects:

```
> lm2 <- lm(y1 ~ density + inorganicN, data = Ena)
> anova(lm2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y1
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
density     1 0.48357 0.48357  3.4113 0.08223 .
inorganicN  1 0.12936 0.12936  0.9126 0.35282  
Residuals  17 2.40983 0.14175
```

Now, it makes a difference whether I use Type I or Type II SS (I know some people object to the terms Type I & II etc. but given the popularity of SAS it's easy short-hand). R anova{stats} uses Type I by default. I can calculate the type II SS, F, and P for density by reversing the order of my main effects or I can use Dr. John Fox's "car" package (companion to applied regression). I prefer the latter method since it is easier for more complex problems.

```
library(car)
Anova(lm2)
            Sum Sq Df F value  Pr(>F)  
density    0.58425  1  4.1216 0.05829 .
inorganicN 0.12936  1  0.9126 0.35282  
Residuals  2.40983 17
```

My understanding is that type II hypotheses would be, "There is no linear effect of x1 on y1 given the effect of (holding constant?) x2" and the same for x2 given x1. I guess this is where I get confused. **What is the hypothesis being tested by the ANOVA using the type I (sequential) method above compared to the hypothesis using the type II method?**

In reality, my data is a bit more complex because I measured numerous metrics of plant growth as well as nutrient dynamics and litter decomposition. My actual analysis is something like:

```
Y <- cbind(y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5)
# Type II
mlm1 <- lm(Y ~ density + nitrate + Npred, data = Ena)
Manova(mlm1)

Type II MANOVA Tests: Pillai test statistic
        Df test stat approx F num Df den Df  Pr(>F)    
density  1   0.34397        1      5     12 0.34269    
nitrate  1   0.99994    40337      5     12 < 2e-16 ***
Npred    1   0.65582        5      5     12 0.01445 * 


# Type I
maov1 <- manova(Y ~ density + nitrate + Npred, data = Ena)
summary(maov1)

          Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df  Pr(>F)    
density    1 0.99950     4762      5     12 < 2e-16 ***
nitrate    1 0.99995    46248      5     12 < 2e-16 ***
Npred      1 0.65582        5      5     12 0.01445 *  
Residuals 16
```

Comment: I think it would be good if a mod added the "canonical question" tag here.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

What you are calling type II SS, I would call type III SS.  Lets imagine that there are just two factors A and B (and we'll throw in the A*B interaction later to distinguish type II SS).  Further, lets imagine that there are different $n$s in the four cells (e.g., $n_{11}$=11, $n_{12}$=9, $n_{21}$=9, and $n_{22}$=11).  Now your two factors are correlated with each other.  (Try this yourself, make 2 columns of 1's and 0's and correlate them, $r=.1$; n.b. it doesn't matter if $r$ is 'significant', this is the whole population that you care about).  The problem with your factors being correlated is that there are sums of squares that are associated with *both* A and B.  When computing an ANOVA (or any other linear regression), we want to *partition* the sums of squares.  A partition puts all sums of squares into *one and only one* of several subsets.  (For example, we might want to divide the SS up into A, B and error.)  However, since your factors (still only A and B here) are not orthogonal there is no unique partition of these SS.  In fact, there can be very many partitions, and if you are willing to slice your SS up into fractions (e.g., "I'll put .5 into this bin and .5 into that one"), there are infinite partitions.  A way to visualize this is to imagine the MasterCard symbol:  The rectangle represents the total SS, and each of the circles represents the SS that are attributable to that factor, but notice the overlap between the circles in the center, those SS could be given to either circle.

[image]

The question is:  How are we to choose the 'right' partition out of all of these possibilities?  Let's bring the interaction back in and discuss some possibilities:

### Type I SS:

- SS(A)
- SS(B|A)
- SS(A*B|A,B)

### Type II SS:

- SS(A|B)
- SS(B|A)
- SS(A*B|A,B)

### Type III SS:

- SS(A|B,A*B)
- SS(B|A,A*B)
- SS(A*B|A,B)

Notice how these different possibilities work.  Only type I SS actually uses those SS in the overlapping portion between the circles in the MasterCard symbol.  That is, the SS that could be attributed to either A or B, *are* actually attributed to one of them when you use type I SS (specifically, the one you entered into the model first).  In both of the other approaches, the overlapping SS are not used *at all*.  Thus, type I SS gives to A all the SS attributable to A (including those that could also have been attributed elsewhere), then gives to B all of the *remaining* SS that are attributable to B, then gives to the A*B interaction all of the *remaining* SS that are attributable to A*B, and leaves the left-overs that couldn't be attributed to anything to the error term.

Type III SS only gives A those SS that are *uniquely* attributable to A, likewise it only gives to B and the interaction those SS that are *uniquely* attributable to them.  The error term only gets those SS that couldn't be attributed to any of the factors.  Thus, those 'ambiguous' SS that could be attributed to 2 or more possibilities are not used.  If you sum the type III SS in an ANOVA table, you will notice that they do not equal the total SS.  In other words, this analysis *must* be wrong, but errs in a kind of epistemically conservative way.  Many statisticians find this approach egregious, however government funding agencies (I believe the FDA) requires their use.

The type II approach is intended to capture what might be worthwhile about the idea behind type III, but mitigate against its excesses.  Specifically, it only adjusts the SS for A and B for each other, not the interaction.  However, in practice type II SS is essentially never used.  You would need to know about all of this and be savvy enough with your software to get these estimates, and the analysts who are typically think this is bunk.

There are more types of SS (I believe IV and V).  They were suggested in the late 60's to deal with certain situations, but it was later shown that they do not do what was thought.  Thus, at this point they are just a historical footnote.

As for what questions these are answering, you basically have that right already in your question:

- Estimates using type I SS tell you how much of the variability in Y can be explained by A, how much of the residual variability can be explained by B, how much of the remaining residual variability can be explained by the interaction, and so on, *in order*.
- Estimates based on type III SS tell you how much of the residual variability in Y can be accounted for by A *after* having accounted for everything else, and how much of the residual variability in Y can be accounted for by B *after* having accounted for everything else as well, and so on.  (Note that both go both first and last simultaneously; if this makes sense to you, and accurately reflects your research question, then use type III SS.)

Comment: thank you for the very helpful answer. The one other area where I get confused is that if "Estimates using type I SS tell you how much of the variability in Y can be explained by A, how much of the residual variability can be explained by B, how much of the remaining residual variability can be explained by the interaction, and so on, in order," then why does the stats associate with A change when additional variables are added? Is it because the tests are based on SS(A)/SS(error) and the error is a function of all the terms in the model? Am I thinking of this correctly?

Comment: By "stats associated with A", I interpret you to mean the F and p-values for the main effect of A.  The F-value for A is the ratio of the Mean Square for A (i.e., SSA / dfA) to the MS error.  As you add more factors, SS are taken from the error term and given to those factors.  In general, this means that MS error goes down, and thus the ratio goes up.  As a result, the F-value for A gets larger and the p-value gets smaller.  Because the degrees of freedom also change it can be more complicated than this, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Oops I did mean MS(A)/MSE for the F statistic. Anyway, your answer is perfect, thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I am curious, about the details of interpretation when using a type I. In my case, density is my only variable of interest and the only one I experimentally manipulated. However unfortunate, density is insignificant on it's own or after accounting for my two other variables of interest (Npredators, inorganicN in type II or III). But because inorganicN apparently explains much of the variation in some of the dependent variables when I add it as the 3rd variable it makes the other 2 highly significant. Therefore, does density really have a significant effect on Y? Is this reasonable?

Comment: You want to avoid fishing, unless you are thinking of this as a pilot study that you will use to effectively plan a confirmatory study.  But, yes, if you intended to determine if there was an effect after having controlled for specific other factors, then this is reasonable.  On a different note, if the answer is what you were looking for, you might accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, this was really useful for my analysis and as a learning experience!

Comment: Pleased to be of service...

Comment: One further comment/question for Type 1 SOS. In the mastercard symbol: if A takes all in A, and B takes the righside without the middle. What is left for the interactions anyways?

Comment: @JonBonJovi, the MasterCard analogy only has 2 factors. If you want 2 factors plus an interaction, then you would need 3 areas that overlap each other somewhat. It is certainly possible to draw an Euler diagram with 3 areas, but I just used the MasterCard symbol for simplicity. For an interaction, imagine a 3rd circle that overlaps the first 2 (eg, it could be centered right-to-left, but mostly above the others); then *all* of the A circle (SS) would go to A, everything in B *that doesn't overlap A* goes to B, & everything in A*B that doesn't overlap *either* A *or* B goes to the interaction.

Comment: This is further question to Gung: So if I do Type 1 SOS with A*B, given A and B. Would I find everything explained by the interaction without the main effect? What does that mean exactly? Would it not explain everything? In short, what does it mean SS(A*B|A,B)? In the graph, A1-B1 bigger or smaller than A2-B2?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica -- I want to love this answer as I usually do your other answers. I'm stuck on the `SS(<stuff>|<stuff>)` notation. It looks like conditioning, but I'm not sure I get how that applies in sums of squares. I'm guessing it's a really good shorthand if one knows what it means. Mind explaining?

Comment: @abalter, I don't see a "`stuff`".  What are you referring to?

Comment: For instance: **SS(A|B,A*B)**

Comment: @abalter, that is the sum of squares due to **A** after having taken into account **B** & the **A*B** interaction.  That's a standard way to write it--you'll find that in any textbook on ANOVA.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, do you have a textbook that you would recommend for learning about these ***types*** at the introductory level?  I'm learning ANOVA in "Probability and Statistics" by Devore, but I don't see any discussion of this.

Comment: @Joe, I would think it's in any ANOVA book.  My favorite is Kutner et al. *Applied Linear Statistical Models*.  I don't have my copy with me right now, but I would suspect it's in there.

Comment: In case anyone reads the comments and is looking for a reference as well, I bought the third edition of Applied Linear Statistical Models by Kutner et al., and it doesn't appear to cover type I vs type II vs type III ANOVA.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that, @Joe, I would hate to waste your money.  FWIW, I think you'll be well served by reading *ALSM*, even if SS are not covered.

Comment: Thank you. No problem. Like you said, it's probably a good book to have.  It may be in the new editions - I bought the 3rd edition to save money.

Comment: I happen to be near my copy of the 5th edition now, @Joe.  Flipping through, I don't see a discussion of the different types of SS.  Surprising, actually.

Answer (score 4):

For illustration I assume a two dimensional ANOVA model specified by `y ~ A * B`

### Type I ANOVA

| Line term in ANOVA table | Hypothesis from model | Hypothesis to model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | y~ A | y~ 1 |
| B | y~ A+B | y~ A |
| A:B | y~ A*B | y~ A+B |

The from-model of every line is the to-model of the line below. The to-model is the from-model without the line term.

### Type II ANOVA

| Line term in ANOVA table | Hypothesis from model | Hypothesis to model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | y~ A+B | y~ B |
| B | y~ A+B | y~ A |
| A:B | y~ A*B | y~ A+B |

The from-model is the full model without all interactions involving the line term. The to-model is the from-model without the line term. This means that the from-model in line B is the full model A*B, but without A*B - that is A+B. The to-model is then A+B without B - that is A.

### Type III ANOVA

In the Anova III model interactions are parameterized such that they are orthogonal to all lower-level interactions. As a consequence it is meaningful to remove a main term from a model even though an interaction involving that term is still present in the model formula. R doesn't have a good formula notation for this, so I define `o(A,B)` as the part of the interaction A:B that is orthogonal to both A and B

| Line term in ANOVA table | Hypothesis from model | Hypothesis to model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | y~ A*B | y~ B + o(A,B) |
| B | y~ A*B | y~ A + o(A,B) |
| A:B | y~ A*B | y~ A+B |

The from-model is always the full model. The to-model is the from model without the line term (but keeping all higher-order orthogonal components of the interactions).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how the operator `o(A,B)` is defined?