# interpret regression result: comparing two levels in a catergorical/factor variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data

for example the data has a binary response `y`, a numerical predictor `week`, and some categorical/factor predictors: `ap`, `hilo`, `ID`, `trt`:

```
   y ap hilo week  ID     trt
1  y  p   hi    0 X01 placebo
2  y  p   hi    2 X01 placebo
3  y  p   hi    4 X01 placebo
4  y  p   hi   11 X01 placebo
5  y  a   hi    0 X02   drug+
6  y  a   hi    2 X02   drug+
7  n  a   hi    6 X02   drug+
8  y  a   hi   11 X02   drug+
9  y  a   lo    0 X03    drug
10 y  a   lo    2 X03    drug
```

Logistic regression result looks like:

```
Coefficients: (4 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  2.550e+00  1.251e+00   2.038 0.041561 *  
app          1.924e+01  8.359e+03   0.002 0.998164    
hilolo      -1.562e+00  1.617e+00  -0.966 0.334074    
week        -2.127e-01  6.377e-02  -3.335 0.000852 ***
IDX02       -2.525e-01  1.721e+00  -0.147 0.883337    
IDX03        2.081e+01  7.562e+03   0.003 0.997804    
IDX04        1.572e+00  1.127e+04   0.000 0.999889    
IDX05        1.572e+00  1.127e+04   0.000 0.999889    
...

Null deviance: 217.38  on 219  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 118.51  on 169  degrees of freedom
AIC: 220.51
```

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 19
It tells us for predictor `ID`, the baseline is `ID == 'X01'` (not shown in result). Comparing  `ID == 'X02'` to `'01'`, the change is not significant, because the p-value is 0.883337.

My question is how do you compare `ID == 'X02'` to `'X03'`? The log adds changes by `2.081e+01 - (-2.525e-01)`, what error do I compare this difference to, and how to calculate p value?

Can somebody give an example using `ID == 'X02'` to `'X03'` please? Thank you.

---

I leave the code later because my question is only about theory. Code in `R`:

```
library(MASS)
library(stats)

data('bacteria')
dat = bacteria

glm_model = glm(y ~ ., family = binomial, data = dat)
summary(glm_model)
```

---

What I know (not very sure, and would like to get verified)

each coefficient has it's estimate and std.error, because there's a population of many different values of this coefficient calculated by using differently sampled data.

So comparing  `ID == 'X02'` to `'X03'` is to compare the mean of two populations. I read [this post](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~cochran/stat10/winter/lectures/lect21.html), so [image]

so, is `delta(x1bar)` in the equation the `std.error` in the glm result? I don't need to divide by `n` any more, right (since the `std.error` in the glm result in already the standard deviation of the mean)?

Comparing `ID == 'X02'` to `'X03'`:

```
z = (-2.525e-01 - 2.081e+01) / sqrt(1.721e+00^2 + 7.562e+03^2)
= -0.002785
```

is this correct? Thanks-

Comment: If you are looking for the coefficients and hypothesis tests to reflect differences between adjacent levels (e.g. `X01` vs `X02`, `X02` vs `X03`, `X03` vs `X04`, etc.), use forward-difference coding. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/contr.sdif.html and https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/ .

Comment: thank you @MAB! I think I prefer not to present in a difference coding - because in practice I have many categorical predictor, for some of them I want to compare adjacent levels, whereas for others I compare all levels to the baseline. If I use the difference coding for some the predictors, it may look confusing - what do you think? Thank you-

Comment: In that case I suggest you look into the `multcomp` package.

Comment: This Q&A although not a direct answer to your question might be useful as I think your answer will also involve the covariance matrix of your coefficients https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93303/variance-covariance-matrix-interpretation