# How to report the results of a GLM from R output

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interpretation, reporting

I am currently writing up my 4th year dissertation in Ecology having completed fieldwork and analysis on the effects of various environmental variables on Butterfly abundance.

I have conductuded a GLM in R that has a series of both categorical and continuous variables and have conducted model simplification, so that I am now left with the following analysis of deviance output in R after running the GLM: 
[image]

I have only ever previously reported ANOVA results using the F statistic in the fashion of (Fx,x=, P=) reporting both the F statistic with both degrees of freedom and the P value for each variable.

However, from this analysis of variance table, their is no F statistic so I am unsure as to how to report the findings of these results?

I know that this summary output can be converted into an ANOVA output using the coommand:

aov(X, test="F")

However, this changes the significance of the P values of some of my variables and I have been advised during a stats course that I only need to report the results from the Analysis of variance table.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for exactly how I should report the significance of each variable please?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: You need to be aware that those p-values represent the "Terms added sequentially (first to last)". That's fine, if that's what you want, but you need to understand what that is. It may help you to read my answer here: [How to interpret type I (sequential) ANOVA and MANOVA?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/7290)