# Will Tukey multiple comparison be the same for different types of Sum Of Squares of ANOVA for an unbalanced design

Tags: r, anova, sums-of-squares, tukey-hsd-test, car

I am working on Two-Way ANOVA for an unbalanced design.

Will Tukey multiple comparison be the same for different types (I, II & III) of  Sum Of Squares of ANOVA for an unbalanced design.

I am doing the ANOVA using the `car` package but the output of the Anova function `car` package does not work with the `TukeyHSD` function. The `TukeyHSD` expects the stats `aov` output.

I have seen posts suggesting the use of `HSD.test` from the `agricolae` package using the linear model `lm`. But the `lm` does not take a `type` argument for the Sum of Squares.

So, does the Tukey comparison be the same for different types of Sum of Squares used for ANOVA?

Below is the sample

**code**:: (warpbreaks is a dataset available in R, I am removing 3 rows to make it unbalanced)

```
library(car)
df <- warpbreaks[-c(1:3), ,]
summary.aov(aov(breaks~wool*tension, df)) # wool: p=.058
car::Anova(aov(breaks~wool*tension, df), type="II") # wool: p=.058
car::Anova(aov(breaks~wool*tension, df), type="III") # wool: p<.05

TukeyHSD(aov(breaks~wool*tension, df))
```

**output**::

```
> summary.aov(aov(breaks~wool*tension, df)) # wool: p=.058
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
wool          1    327   327.1   2.940 0.093269 .  
tension       2   1954   976.8   8.780 0.000603 ***
wool:tension  2   1257   628.3   5.647 0.006484 ** 
Residuals    45   5006   111.3                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> car::Anova(aov(breaks~wool*tension, df), type="II") # wool: p=.058
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: breaks
             Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
wool          476.7  1  4.2847 0.0442255 *  
tension      1953.6  2  8.7800 0.0006034 ***
wool:tension 1256.5  2  5.6472 0.0064836 ** 
Residuals    5006.4 45                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> car::Anova(aov(breaks~wool*tension, df), type="III") # wool: p<.05
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: breaks
              Sum Sq Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)  14113.5  1 126.8594 1.100e-14 ***
wool          1480.3  1  13.3055 0.0006846 ***
tension       2641.6  2  11.8721 7.236e-05 ***
wool:tension  1256.5  2   5.6472 0.0064836 ** 
Residuals     5006.4 45                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> TukeyHSD(aov(breaks~wool*tension, df))
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = breaks ~ wool * tension, data = df)

$wool
         diff       lwr       upr     p adj
B-A -5.074074 -11.03392 0.8857766 0.0932694

$tension
          diff       lwr       upr     p adj
M-L -10.451852 -19.38891 -1.514795 0.0184375
H-L -15.174074 -24.11113 -6.237018 0.0004701
H-M  -4.722222 -13.24337  3.798927 0.3792099

$`wool:tension`
               diff       lwr        upr     p adj
B:L-A:L -20.2777778 -36.82155  -3.734005 0.0084280
A:M-A:L -24.5000000 -41.04377  -7.956227 0.0008625
B:M-A:L -19.7222222 -36.26600  -3.178449 0.0111663
A:H-A:L -23.9444444 -40.48822  -7.400671 0.0011784
B:H-A:L -29.7222222 -46.26600 -13.178449 0.0000407
A:M-B:L  -4.2222222 -19.01942  10.574978 0.9563376
B:M-B:L   0.5555556 -14.24164  15.352756 0.9999974
A:H-B:L  -3.6666667 -18.46387  11.130534 0.9761080
B:H-B:L  -9.4444444 -24.24164   5.352756 0.4157897
B:M-A:M   4.7777778 -10.01942  19.574978 0.9277630
A:H-A:M   0.5555556 -14.24164  15.352756 0.9999974
B:H-A:M  -5.2222222 -20.01942   9.574978 0.8980170
A:H-B:M  -4.2222222 -19.01942  10.574978 0.9563376
B:H-B:M -10.0000000 -24.79720   4.797200 0.3522966
B:H-A:H  -5.7777778 -20.57498   9.019423 0.8521900
```

Since for all three types of Sum of Squares (types I, II & III) the Residuals are the same, will the Tukeys comparisons done by using type I ANOVA model with 
`TukeyHSD(aov(breaks~wool*tension, df))` 
still be valid for type II & III ANOVA's.

**Further observation**:
Wool has only two levels A and B so in effect the Tukeys comparison p-value for wool should agree with the ANOVA result.

[image: p-value for wool from different tests]

As can be seen it matches type I and does not match the other two.

So if I have a P-threshold of 0.05, Type II & Type III ANOVA suggest that wool is significant and it do not agree with the Type I ANOVA and the TukeyHSD.

Can it be concluded that Tukey test cannot be done using R for type II and III Sum of Squares?

Comment: That depends against _which error term_ mean square you run the post-hoc test. _Normally_ (by default in most software, I expect, but I'm not sure about R) we test a post-hoc against the error term of the whole model, and this error is the same be it SS I, II, or III. Therefore Tukey will be the same. But if, for example, you choose the interaction's term mean square as the error term for the test, it will depend - since interaction's SS is potentially affected by the SS type.

Comment: @ttnphns: From what I understand (after reading e.g. [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20452/how-to-interpret-type-i-type-ii-and-type-iii-anova-and-manova/20455#20455): the error term _DOES_ change depending on the type of SS. For type III, anything that can't be attributed _uniquely_ to one factor or interaction will become part of the error term. For type I, only those SS that are not part of either any factor or any interaction of factors go into the error term. So, your error term will differ depending on the type of SS and according to you could change the p-hoc result.

Comment: @evoked_potential, No you aren't correct. SS type affects individual effects size/signifivance, but not effect or error of the whole model. `For type III, anything that can't be attributed uniquely to one factor or interaction will become part of the error term` No, that "anything" gets thrown away.

Comment: @ttnphns: Thanks for the correction, I mixed that up. All _ambiguous_ parts are thrown away and only those parts that could not be associated with _any_ of the factors or interactions become part of the error term.