# I don't know how to calculate SS(A), SS(A|B), SS(A|A*B), SS(A*B|A,B), etc

Tags: regression, anova, interaction, treatment-effect, deviance

I read gung's answer to "[How to interpret type I, type II, and type III ANOVA and MANOVA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20452/how-to-interpret-type-i-type-ii-and-type-iii-anova-and-manova)".

Instead of messing with R I'd like to just create my own linear model in a spreadsheet. The problem is that I understood what is SS(something|something) on an intuitive level, but not on a mathematical level. I don't know the formulas.

What I'm looking for is instructions on how to calculate SS(something|something) where something can be a simple effects, an interaction of 2 simple effects, an interaction of a lot of simple effects, or any set thereof (eg., 3 simple effects and the combinations of all of them), in the most general way possible.

Comment: These formulas should be in any introductory statisitcs textbook that covers ANOVA.  Try 
Applied Linear Statistical Models (McGraw-Hill/Irwin Series Operations and Decision Sciences) 5th Edition.

Comment: Do you know how do you read them by English names instead of symbols? So I could search the web. I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean.  Are you trying to find out you would say "SS(A|A*B)" in English words for example?  If so, this is simply "The sum of squares of A given the interaction of A and B).  I'm not sure you will have much luck searching the web on these terms though.  This might be of help to you, however:  https://books.google.com/books?id=tvNZ6A7bvbQC&pg=PA417&lpg=PA417&dq=SS(A%7CA*B)+interaction&source=bl&ots=UkFY4Uv13d&sig=rZOufYZQ0z7ixypK6dfcCYhcAbg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin2KLwmrfRAhVD7yYKHb88B5sQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=SS(A%7CA*B)%20interaction&f=false.

Comment: "Are you trying to find out you would say…" Yes, that was it.