# two-way ANOVA in R; model effects & F table lookup

Tags: r, anova

I'm moving from JMP to R for my statistical analysis and have noticed that the two-way ANOVA test function aov() does not report model effect.  This is standard in JMP and to me it's essential for hypothesis testing, as one can't assume a main effect if there isn't a Model effect.

1. My first question, is there a reason why model effects aren't evaluated in the hypothesis testing within the R community?
2. My second question is, if Model effects aren't built into the aov() function then how can I use R to access the F table to obtain the model effect and prob > F?

##Calculate model effects with a F table lookup.

```
Data.X <- data.frame(mtcars)
fit.ANOVA <- aov(mpg ~ cyl * gear, data = Data.X)
tests <- as.data.frame(summary(fit.ANOVA)[[1]])
Model.Effect.AOV.DF.M <- sum(tests$Df[1:(nrow(tests) - 1)])
Model.Effect.AOV.DF.error <- tests$Df[nrow(tests)]
Model.Effect.AOV.SS <- sum(tests$`Sum Sq`[1:(nrow(tests) - 1)])
Model.Effect.AOV.MS <- Model.Effect.AOV.SS / Model.Effect.AOV.DF
Model.Effect.AOV.FRatio <- Model.Effect.AOV.MS / tests$`Mean Sq`[nrow(tests)]
Model.Effect.AOV.Fcrit.0.05 <- qf(1 -0.05, df1 = Model.Effect.AOV.DF.error, df2=Model.Effect.AOV.DF.M)
#You should not reject the null if your F critical value is smaller than your F Ratio (F Value).
if(Model.Effect.AOV.Fcrit.0.05 <= Model.Effect.AOV.FRatio){
  print('Data Contains Significantly Different Populations')
} else {
  print('Data is the same Population')
}
```

Comment: Note that `cyl` and `gear` are treated as numeric variables in the `mtcars` data set, so the example isn't a traditional two-way anova.  I think it makes sense to treat these variables as factor variables.  This doesn't affect the import of the question.

Comment: You are completely correct Sal Mangiafico.  This should be a Factorial ANOVA.  I'll edit the example to reflect this.

Comment: I wouldn't mess with the example.  I think it perfectly illustrates your question.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: If this question is off topic for this site, then where should it go?

Comment: Because it's really about R programming, and not statistics per se, it really belongs on Stack Overflow.  There is some way to migrate it there, but I'm not sure if a moderator needs to do that.  In any case, don't re-post the question elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `lm` function for general linear models, the `summary` will give you *p* value for the model, which is what you are looking for.  In general, I recommend using `lm` and then using `Anova` in the *car* package to produce the anova table.  Note that the `Anova` function uses type II sums of squares by default, while `aov` and `anova` uses type I sums of squares.  You could use `anova(model)` if you wanted type I SS. It appears that JMP uses type III sums of squares by default. The `Anova` function can also produce type III SS, but you need to specify the `contrasts` in the model, as explained on [R Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/anova-%E2%80%93-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/).

```
if(!require(car)){install.packages("car")}

model = lm(mpg ~ cyl * gear, data = mtcars)

summary(model)

   ### Residual standard error: 3.198 on 28 degrees of freedom
   ### Multiple R-squared:  0.7457, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7185 
   ### F-statistic: 27.38 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 1.786e-08

f = summary(model)$fstatistic

f

   ###    value    numdf    dendf 
   ### 27.37524  3.00000 28.00000 

p <- pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)

p

   ###        value 
   ### 1.785687e-08 

library(car)

Anova(model)

   ### Anova Table (Type II tests)
   ###
   ###       Sum Sq Df F value   Pr(>F)    
   ### cyl       563.40  1 55.0992 4.39e-08 ***
   ### gear        5.43  1  0.5312   0.4722    
   ### cyl:gear   16.60  1  1.6234   0.2131    
   ### Residuals 286.30 28
```

Comment: +1 particularly for differentiating the types of sums of squares, the statistical issue here. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20452/28500) for a very useful introduction to that issue.

Comment: Thanks @EdM.  I added this aspect to my answer.  I believe the type I vs. type II distinction won't matter for the "model effect" that the OP is looking for.

Comment: The distinction might, however, matter for others who come upon this page later.

Comment: Yes, it definitely matters in the anova table, and when trying to replicate results from other packages!

Comment: Thank you for the tip Sal Mangiafico, and yes, the Type III information will help me in my future use with R programming.

Comment: @JamesR you could also consider the `anova` function provided by Harrell's [`rms package`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rms). It "tests most meaningful hypotheses in a design" via Wald tests that combine a predictor with its interactions to evaluate both its overall significance and the significance of its interactions, produce joint tests of all interactions in a model, etc. For that you have to use the `rms` versions of standard functions (e.g., `ols` versus `lm`) and there is a learning curve, but if you will be doing a lot of modeling it is well worth the effort.