# What test exactly does lm.anova perform in R?

Tags: r, anova, lm

I have always thought that `anova(myFit)` performs submodel test for each regressor in the model (i.e. comparing model with all regressors with model without the tested regressor). However, this is clearly not true.

Toy example:

```r
set.seed(0)
n = 20
data = data.frame(
  Y = rbinom(n,20,0.5),
  X1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], n, T),
  X2 = rbinom(n,6,0.5)
)

anova(lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = data))
# Analysis of Variance Table
# Response: Y
#           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
# X1         2  1.883  0.9413  0.1677 0.8471
# X2         1  3.265  3.2648  0.5817 0.4568
# Residuals 16 89.803  5.6127

anova(lm(Y ~ X2, data = data), lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = data))
# Analysis of Variance Table
# Model 1: Y ~ X2
# Model 2: Y ~ X1 + X2
#   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
# 1     18 92.908
# 2     16 89.803  2    3.1057 0.2767 0.7619
```

In the second case the comparison of change in RSS is performed resulting in F(2,16) =  0.2767. What test is performed in the first case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R has comprehensive documentation. For this specific case `help(anova.lm)` says:

> Details:
>
> Specifying a single object gives a sequential analysis of variance
>        table for that fit.  That is, the reductions in the residual sum
>        of squares as each term of the formula is added in turn are given
>        in as the rows of a table, plus the residual sum of squares.
>
> The table will contain F statistics (and P values) comparing the
>        mean square for the row to the residual mean square.
>
> If more than one object is specified, the table has a row for the
>        residual degrees of freedom and sum of squares for each model.
>        For all but the first model, the change in degrees of freedom and
>        sum of squares is also given. (This only make statistical sense if
>        the models are nested.)  It is conventional to list the models
>        from smallest to largest, but this is up to the user.
>
> Optionally the table can include test statistics.  Normally the F
>        statistic is most appropriate, which compares the mean square for
>        a row to the residual sum of squares for the largest model
>        considered.  If ‘scale’ is specified chi-squared tests can be
>        used. Mallows' Cp statistic is the residual sum of squares plus
>        twice the estimate of sigma^2 times the residual degrees of
>        freedom.

So, for the first case in your example, instead of comparing each covariate with the intercept-only model the covariates are added to the model one by one, hence the order matters. i.e.

```
> anova(lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = data))
Analysis of Variance Table
Response: Y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
X1         2  1.883  0.9413  0.1677 0.8471
X2         1  3.265  3.2648  0.5817 0.4568
Residuals 16 89.803  5.6127


> anova(lm(Y ~ X2 + X1, data = data))
Analysis of Variance Table
Response: Y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
X2         1  2.042  2.0417  0.3638 0.5549
X1         2  3.106  1.5528  0.2767 0.7619
Residuals 16 89.803  5.6127
```

For the second case it compares the sequence of nested models with the first one:

```
> anova(lm(Y ~ 1, data = data), lm(Y ~ X1, data = data), lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = data))
Analysis of Variance Table
Model 1: Y ~ 1
Model 2: Y ~ X1
Model 3: Y ~ X1 + X2
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     19 94.950
2     17 93.067  2    1.8825 0.1677 0.8471
3     16 89.803  1    3.2648 0.5817 0.4568
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!

Comment: Also note that, for the one model case, people often don't want Type I (sequential) sums of squares.  It's kind of a quirk with R, relative to some other software packages, that the default analysis is Type I SS.  For general linear models (*lm()*), the usual go-to function is *car::Anova*.

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/28500) provides a superb introduction to the different Types of ANOVA.