# why different results with summary()and anova() function in linear mixed effect model

Tags: regression, anova

I know that the question has been submitted several times but given my level of knowledge, I'm afraid I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer.
I have two fixed effects :  frequency (high vs low) and predictability (high vs low).
my model is as follows :

```
m1=lmer(log(FF) ~ frequence * Predic + (1 | Sujet) + (1 | item), data= FreqPredicExpert72)

The anova function returns : 

Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                  Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
Predic           1.78800 1.78800     1 68.035 23.1208 8.774e-06 ***
frequence        0.78005 0.78005     1 68.155 10.0869  0.002243 ** 
Predic:frequence 0.16368 0.16368     1 67.894  2.1166  0.150321   

The summary function returns : 


Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: log(FF) ~ Predic * frequence + (1 | Sujet) + (1 | item)
   Data: FreqPredicExpert72
REML criterion at convergence: 558.9
Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.6928 -0.5517 -0.0021  0.5770  4.3347 
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 item     (Intercept) 0.002058 0.04536 
 Sujet    (Intercept) 0.014550 0.12062 
 Residual             0.077333 0.27809 
Number of obs: 1580, groups:  item, 72; Sujet, 28
Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           5.33733    0.02883 49.82410 185.118   <2e-16 ***
PredicHP             -0.05921    0.02490 67.27315  -2.378   0.0202 *  
frequenceHF          -0.03042    0.02489 67.28622  -1.222   0.2260    
PredicHP:frequenceHF -0.05133    0.03528 67.89410  -1.455   0.1503    

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) PrdcHP frqnHF
PredicHP    -0.428              
frequenceHF -0.429  0.497       
PrdcHP:frHF  0.302 -0.705 -0.705
```

There is no difference concerning p value fonte interaction, but as on can see, anova returns a significant effect of frequency (p = 0.002243 ** ) while this effect is not significant in results with summary (p = 0.2260). For me it's a big problem.

My question is threefold

**1)** Why both p value of the interaction and  p value of the Predic effect are identical in summary() and in anova() function? And why it is not the case for the frequency effect?

**2)** In what outcome can we trust? (Anova or summary?). Pratically, effect of frequency amounted to 6 ms in the group of 21 adults. It seems unlikely that this effect is significant. So I will tend to rely on results from the summary() rather than anova()

**3)** What I have just described is part of my data. IN fact, I have three groups of participants (grade 3, grade 5 and Adults).

To analyse my data, I conducted a 3 way-anova : Group x frequency x Predic
The model used is as follows :

```
m1=lmer(log(FF) ~ Group * frequence * Predic + (1 | Sujet) + (1 | item), data= FreqPredicExpert72)
```

For this model, anova() and summary() returns very different results. If I understand correctly, it’s because summary() function tests contrasts?
Is it possible to specify something so that summary function gives global effect for the Group x frequency x Predic interaction as in anova() function. Does this have anything to do with contrast specification?

Comment: i apologize for the the table which are not formatted correctly

Comment: Is there some reason you are using Type III Anova? And just how was Type III defined in this implementation? See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20452/28500) about these difficulties. Also, the order of entry of predictors into the model can matter in some Types of `anova()`. In the first model with "Type II!" Anova you entered `frequence * Predic ` but in the model reported by Summary it was in the order `Predic * frequency`. Check if that makes a difference for the `anova()` result. (Order shouldn't affect the Summary result.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have no reason to use Type III Anova. Changing the order ( frequency * Predict or Predic* frequency) have no effect on p value in anova or in summary function. Using car::Anova(time.lm, type = 3) gives the Sams p values as the summary() function. Do you think that the use of summary is better than the use of anova given that car::Anova(time.lm, type = 3) and the Anova(m1, type=c("III"))  give same results as summary() function? Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear: the first `anova()` function presented in your question was from the `lmerTest` package. Working on a single object produced by `lmer()`, does that function (with its default `type="III"` setting) give different results from `Anova()` (with a `type=3` setting) in the `car` package? Also, are your objects `time.lm` and `m1` the same? It would be best to clarify those issues by editing the question itself, to make it easier for others to find the information. Also, comments can sometimes be lost.

Comment: I'll try to be clear, the problem concerns the p value for the factor "frequence"  : 
1) P value is significant (p<.001)when i use  anova(m1), anova(m1, type = 2) or car::Anova(m1)
2) P value becomes NOT significant ( p = 0.22) when i use Anova(m1, type=c("III")) or summary() function
So, what is the most likely outcome, given that inspection of the data shows a very limited effect of frequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This apparent discrepancy comes from the difficulty in interpreting "main effects" (e.g., the coefficient for `frequence` reported by `summary()`, or a Type III Anova test) when there is an interaction.

With the standard treatment coding default in R, the significance test for `frequence` reported by `summary()` in your interaction model will examine whether the coefficient is different from 0 *when `predictability` is at its reference level*. It looks like the reference levels for `frequence` and `predictability` are both set at "low" in your model. As a concrete example say that there is a significant interaction between the two predictors, with 0 influence of `frequence` on outcome when `predictability` is "low" but a large influence when `predictability` is "high".

Then the coefficient reported by `summary()` for `frequence` should be insignificant, with a coefficient of 0! That's because *at the reference level of* `predictability` there is no influence of `frequence` on outcome. That doesn't mean that `frequence` is unimportant. You would still have a large interaction coefficient involving it. And if you simply set the reference level for `predictability` to "high" then the coefficient reported by `summary()` for `frequence` would now be significantly different from 0.

So you have to be very circumspect when interpreting apparent "main effects" when predictors are included in interactions. As another example, just centering a continuous predictor can change the apparent "significance" of individual coefficients for all predictors interacting with it.

In your case there is an interaction coefficient (-0.05133) of magnitude similar to that of the "main effect" of `predictability` (-0.05921, for the case of "low" `frequence`), even though it didn't reach the magical threshold of 5% significance. The combination of the interaction term and the "main effect" of `frequence` (-0.03042) would estimate an effect of `frequence` at "high" `predictability` of -0.08175, which might well pass that threshold. Try switching the reference level of `predictability` and see for yourself.

This difficulty with interpreting the results of `summary()` will only be compounded in your final 3-way interaction model. The "main effects" for each predictor would be when *both* of the others are at their reference levels, however those were chosen.

Type III Anova can lead to similar difficulties in interpretation, as the significance of `frequence` will be assessed after the contributions of both `predictability` *and* the interaction between `frequence` and `predictability` are evaluated. So an "insignificant" effect of `frequence` doesn't mean it isn't important, just that its "main effect" is dwarfed in part by its interaction with `predictability`. As @gung puts it in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/28500), there is an inherent problem with Type III Anova that can lead to false negative results:

> If you sum the type III [sum of squares] SS in an ANOVA table, you will notice that they do not equal the total SS. In other words, this analysis must be wrong, but errs in a kind of epistemically conservative way.

Or, as the Warning in the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf) page for the `car` `Anova()` function puts it:

> Be careful of type-III tests.

In your particular case, one might argue that the lack of a statistically significant interaction term (at least in the 2-predictor model) could allow you to revert to a simple additive model. Then this problem would go away, although you should report that you first tested the interaction model.

What you presumably care most about is whether `frequence` is associated with outcome whether or not that association is primarily due to an interaction with `predictability`. With fixed-effect models the [`rms` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rms) in R handles this nicely by doing a Wald-type test of whether all of the coefficients (up to 2-way interactions) involving a predictor are 0, taking into account the covariances among the coefficient estimates. I don't work much with mixed models but there should be ways to do the same analysis for those. That *might* be how `Anova()` in `car` performs its Wald tests (as opposed to its default likelihood-ratio tests), but I'm not sure. You might also consider the [`emmeans` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=emmeans) as a tool for evaluating effects of interest in mixed models with interaction terms.

What I'm still confused about is why the "Type III" test reported by `anova()` from the [`lmerTest` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=lmerTest) gave a significant coefficient for `frequence` while the other Type III tests didn't. But that's seems to be more a question of software implementation than a statistical issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. I think that I better understand my problem. As proposed, I will try to use emmeans package to evaluate in particular effect of frequency.  Many thanks again for your response.

Comment: @rach just remember that with interaction terms there is no single "effect of frequency." Its "effect" depends on the levels of all the other predictors interacting with it.

Comment: So as I understand it, if I'm interesting in the single "effect of frequency", I should test it in a model as m1=lmer(log(FF) ~ frequence + Predic + (1 | Sujet) + (1 | item), data= FreqPredicExpert72), where the interaction terms does not appears?

Comment: @rach yes, but if there is truly an interaction there is no "single effect of frequency." For example, in an observational study with a true interaction, the apparent "single effect of frequency" would depend on the relative number of cases having `Predic="low"` and `Predic="high"`. Those are the types of problems that `emmeans` can help with. In your particular case with an insignificant interaction term you could justify proceeding that way, but you might miss finding something important that further study could elucidate.

Comment: Ok @EDM, All this information is very formative and useful. In fact, I have several groups, some in which frequency x Predic interaction is significant, other not (I do this because I have initially a significant interaction between Groups, frequency and Predic). So, according to the p value of the interaction, I can or not focus on single/main effects. I will try to use emmeans function and post the outcome. Very pleased with your advice!

Comment: @rach in that case there certainly will be no "single effect of frequency." You need to display results for different combinations of Group, frequency, and predictability and gauge significance of differences between specific combinations of interest, as you should be able to with `emmeans`.

Comment: Dear @EDM, I apply emmeans, and effectively, each combinaison of the factors are compared, for example frequency (High F vs Low F) and Predic (High P vs Low P) lead to four comparisons. Than you again, you helped me clear up the problem, it allows me to better understand the different analyses to be considered according to hypotheses and results. Very happy!

Comment: @rach if your question has been answered then please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm just adding that when interaction is not significant and is remove from the model frequence + Predic  rather than frequence * Predic, anova() and summary return same p value for each factor.