# Which R functions are correct for estimating partial Eta Squared for effects in multiple linear regression with interaction terms?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, interaction, effect-size

There are a few functions in R available for calculating partial Eta Squared, such as:
`effectsize::eta_squared`
`rstatix::partial_eta_squared`
`sjstats::anova_stats`
`heplots::etasq`
`DescTools::EtaSq`
`lsr::etaSquared`

However, **when running it on a multiple regression model (with an
interaction), I get different partial eta squared estimations depending on the function** I use.
It seems that the first three functions produce the same estimates but which differ from the estimates produced by the latter three functions.

Example:
LM model specification:

`istanb.lm.INT2   <- lm(istanb.uk.NA   ~ crt.uk + aot.uk.NA +  PolitID + SBS.NA + sex + age + education  + PolitID * aot.uk.NA, data = istanb.df, na.action = na.omit)`

#Partial eta results from `heplots::etasq`, `DescTools::EtaSq`, `lsr::etaSquared`:
[image: #Partial eta results from heplots::etasq, DescTools::EtaSq, lsr::etaSquared:]

#Partial eta squared estimates from `effectsize::eta_squared`, `sjstats::eta_sq`, `sjstats::anova_stats`, `rstatix::partial_eta_squared`

[image: #Partial eta squared estimates from effectsize::eta_squared, sjstats::eta_sq, sjstats::anova_stats, rstatix::partial_eta_squared:]

The summary of the multiple linear model in question is presented in
the following figure:
[image: summary of the multiple linear model in question]

I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on what seems
to be the cause of these differences, and which calculation is more appropriate for a multiple linear model with an interaction.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: This question is about the difference among six R functions with a similar name. The trick to finding the answer is to read their documentation. However, six functions is a bit much; and it's better anyway to know one function but to know it well, so I focus on `DescTools::EtaSq`. The process (reading the documentation to learn what a function does) is straightforward to apply to the other functions.

---

Let's start with the definition of eta-squared $\eta^2$ and partial eta-squared $\eta^2_p$. These quantities are measures of effect size and they extend the squared correlation $r^2$ to models with more than one predictor.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\eta^2 &=
  \frac{\operatorname{SS}_{\text{effect}}}{\operatorname{SS}_{\text{total}}} =
  \frac{\operatorname{SS}_{\text{effect}}}{\sum_i\left(y_i-\bar{y}\right)^2} \\
\eta^2_p &=
  \frac{\operatorname{SS}_{\text{effect}}}{\operatorname{SS}_{\text{effect}} + \operatorname{SS}_{\text{error}}} =
  \frac{\operatorname{SS}_{\text{effect}}}{\operatorname{SS}_{\text{effect}} + \sum_i\hat{e}_i^2}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\bar{y}$ is the average outcome and the $\hat{e}_i$s are the residuals. So $\eta^2$ is the effect size relative to the total variation in the outcome Y, while $\eta^2_p$ is on the scale of the variability which remains after removing the effect of other terms from the denominator. $\eta^2_p$ is considered easier to compare between studies because the total variability $\operatorname{SS}_{\text{total}}$ depends on the study design.

In a simple linear regression, $r^2 = \eta^2 = \eta^2_p$ where $r$ is the Pearson's correlation between the (single) predictor *x* and the outcome *y*.

In a multiple linear regression, we use analysis of variance to compute the sums of squares (SS). And there are (at least) three types of sums of squares. Somewhat unhelpfully, they are called type 1, 2 and 3 (or type I, II and III) and they differ in how they partition the total sum of squares. See [How to interpret type I, type II, and type III ANOVA and MANOVA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20452/237901) to learn more; here is a summary.

Using the notation from the linked CV post, let's assume that the model is Y ~ A + B + A:B (two main effects + their interaction).

- Type I is sequential and terms are "added" to the model in order, first the main effects, then the interactions; the type I sum of squares are SS(A), SS(B|A), SS(A:B|A,B)
- Type II adjust the contribution of a predictor for other main effects (but not its interactions, if any): SS(A|B), SS(B|A), SS(A:B|A,B)
- Type III attributes to each term (main effect or interaction) its unique contribution. So the sum of squares due to A *excludes* the effect of the interaction between A and B: SS(A|B,A:B), SS(B|A,A:B), SS(A:B|A,B).

So this explains the differences between the various eta-squared functions: they have different defaults, so they don't use the same SS type to compute (partial) eta-squared. It's best to be explicit and specify the sum of squares type rather than let the software make a choice for you.

Furthermore, the three SS types are not necessarily different. For example, designs of controlled experiments are often balanced so that the terms A, B an A:B are orthogonal to each other and their contributions don't overlap. (In that case, SS(A|B) = SS(A), etc.; so the conditioning and the order don't matter.) This likely won't be the case in an observational study.

For a recommendation, which calculation is most appropriate for a model with interactions, note that the distinction is in how the contribution of the main effects is computed. Type I doesn't seem very convincing as why would the effect size of A depend on whether we fit the model Y ~ A * B or the model Y ~ B * A. So it's probably best to choose either type II or type III. Alternatively (though this doesn't correspond to an "accepted" SS type) pool together the main effect and the interaction(s) of a predictor to estimate its sum of squares and thus its effect size: SS(A|B,A:B) + SS(A:B|A,B). This approach is described in the section [Learning From a Saturated Model](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/multivar.html#learning-from-a-saturated-model) of [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) by Prof. Frank Harrell. (Caution: The application in RMS is to estimate the predictive potential of a predictor, not to estimate its effect size.)

For illustration purposes, I show how to reproduce the output of `DescTools::EtaSq` by implementing functions to extract the sum of squares from an anova table and compute eta-squared and partial eta-squared. The `DescTools::EtaSq`'s default is type II.

```
# Fit an ANOVA with the main effects and an interaction.
model <- aov(Y ~ A + B + A:B, data = data)

# Type I sum of squares and partial eta-squared
# DescTools::EtaSq(model, type = 1)
compute_eta_squared(
  extract_sum_squares(model, anova(model))
)
#>     eta.squared partial.eta.squared
#> A    0.15752020          0.29543977
#> B    0.43518845          0.53671296
#> A:B  0.03163959          0.07768294

# Type II sum of squares and partial eta-squared
# DescTools::EtaSq(model, type = 2)
compute_eta_squared(
  extract_sum_squares(model, car::Anova(model, type = 2))
)
#>     eta.squared partial.eta.squared
#> A    0.18269789          0.32721054
#> B    0.43518845          0.53671296
#> A:B  0.03163959          0.07768294

# Type III sum of squares and partial eta-squared
# DescTools::EtaSq(model, type = 3)
compute_eta_squared(
  extract_sum_squares(model, car::Anova(model, type = 3))
)
#>     eta.squared partial.eta.squared
#> A    0.18718333          0.33257224
#> B    0.44662269          0.54315526
#> A:B  0.03163959          0.07768294
```

---

The full R code listing:

```
library("tidyverse")

extract_sum_squares <- function(model, anova) {
  y <- fitted(model) + residuals(model)
  SS <- anova["Sum Sq"]

  SSeffect <- subset(SS, !(rownames(SS) %in% c("(Intercept)", "Residuals")))
  SSerror <- SS["Residuals", ]
  SStotal <- sum((y - mean(y))^2)

  list(
    SSeffect = SSeffect,
    SSerror = SSerror,
    SStotal = SStotal
  )
}

compute_eta_squared <- function(SS) {
  cbind(
    setNames(SS$SSeffect / SS$SStotal, "eta.squared"),
    setNames(SS$SSeffect / (SS$SSeffect + SS$SSerror), "partial.eta.squared")
  )
}

set.seed(1234)

data <-
  crossing(
    ID = seq(8),
    A = factor(1:3),
    B = factor(1:3)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Y = as.numeric(A) + as.numeric(B) + rnorm(n())
  )

# "Break" the balanced design by sampling 80% of the rows
# Comment this line out to see that the three SS types are the same when the design is balanced
data <- sample_frac(data, .8)

# For type 3 sum of squares, it is recommended to fit models with
# "sum" factor encoding and centered covariates.
data$A <- C(data$A, "contr.sum")
data$B <- C(data$B, "contr.sum")

# Fit an ANOVA with the main effects and an interaction.
model <- aov(Y ~ A + B + A:B, data = data)

# Type I sum of squares and partial eta-squared
DescTools::EtaSq(model, type = 1)
compute_eta_squared(
  extract_sum_squares(model, anova(model))
)

# Type II sum of squares and partial eta-squared
DescTools::EtaSq(model, type = 2)
compute_eta_squared(
  extract_sum_squares(model, car::Anova(model, type = 2))
)

# Type III sum of squares and partial eta-squared
DescTools::EtaSq(model, type = 3)
compute_eta_squared(
  extract_sum_squares(model, car::Anova(model, type = 3))
)
```

Comment: Many thanks - makes sense! I had suspected it had to do with using different types of SSs, but hadn't dug deep enough in the documentation! effectsize::eta_squared() is the only option available that also returns confidence intervals on the partial eta squared. To get partial eta squareds using type 2 or type 3 SSs one can apparently use effectsize::eta_squared(Anova(fit, type=3))). But one has to use effect coding using afex::set_sum_contrasts() and center all covariates using scale() in the mode formula.

Comment: @TomWenseleers It sounds like I should look into the effectsize as well. Makes sense that a package specially for effect size calculations provides more options. I've used DescTools before, so that's why I went with it. Also, on the models I tried it on, the effectsize::eta_squared default is type 1, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yes indeed effectsize::eta_squared(fit) and effectsize::eta_squared(anova(fit)) both return type I (which is not very useful) but effectsize::eta_squared(Anova(fit, type=2 or 3))) can be used to get partial eta squared with type II or type III tests. Only thing is if you use type III that you have to remember to use sum contrasts / effecting coding & center all covariates. A function effectsize::eta_squared(fit, type=XX) could have been more logical...