# Why does the Type-3 ANOVA using LRT via car::Anova() give different result than term-by-term LRT model comparison via anova() in R?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, likelihood-ratio, model-comparison

With this very simple data:

```
> A
 [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b"
> B
 [1] "x" "y" "x" "y" "x" "y" "x" "y" "x" "x" "x" "x"
> C
 [1] "l" "l" "m" "m" "l" "l" "m" "m" "l" "l" "l" "l"
> response
 [1] 14 30 15 35 50 51 30 32 51 55 53 55
```

I try to reproduce the Type-3 car::Anova by using step-by-step term elimination to better understand interactions and analysis of variance.

For example I want to assess the term "C"

```
> options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
> m1 <- lm(response ~ A*B*C)  # the full model

> car::Anova(m1, type=3, test.statistic = "LR")
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: response
            Sum Sq Df F value  Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)   9374  1 1802.78 1.8e-06 ***
A              716  1  137.69  0.0003 ***
B              182  1   35.00  0.0041 ** 

C              178  1   34.23  0.0043 ** 

A:B            178  1   34.23  0.0043 ** 
A:C            317  1   61.03  0.0014 ** 
B:C              8  1    1.63  0.2714    
A:B:C            0  1    0.00  0.9755    
Residuals       21  4                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

For term "C" I got p-value = 0.0043
Now I going to assess term C by elimination:

```
> m2 <- lm(response ~ A + B + A:B)  # the term "C", eliminated all terms with C
> anova(m1, m2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: response ~ A * B * C
Model 2: response ~ A + B + A:B
  Res.Df RSS Df Sum of Sq    F Pr(>F)   
1      4  21                            
2      8 648 -4      -627 30.1  0.003 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here p-value is = 0.003.
Close but not the same.
This is the simplest general linear model, no mixed effects, no transformations.

When I typed "test = LRT"

```
> anova(m1, m2, test="LRT")
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: response ~ A * B * C
Model 2: response ~ A + B + A:B
  Res.Df RSS Df Sum of Sq Pr(>Chi)    
1      4  21                          
2      8 648 -4      -627   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The result is totally different.

Please note, my goal IS NOT to make any formal inference, only to UNDERSTAND the calculations behind. I understand, that elimination terms from model should be equivalent to the car::Anova() and give equal result numerically.

Let's confirm:

```
> drop1(m1, scope = ~A*B*C, test="F")
Single term deletions

Model:
response ~ A * B * C
       Df Sum of Sq RSS  AIC F value Pr(>F)    
<none>               21 22.6                   
A       1       716 737 63.4  137.69 0.0003 ***
B       1       182 203 47.9   35.00 0.0041 ** 

C       1       178 199 47.7   34.23 0.0043 ** 

A:B     1       178 199 47.7   34.23 0.0043 ** 
A:C     1       317 338 54.1   61.03 0.0014 ** 
B:C     1         8  29 24.7    1.63 0.2714    
A:B:C   1         0  21 20.6    0.00 0.9755    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

It works! It agrees with car::Anova().

So how should I eliminate the terms to obtain the same result using anova()? Evidently comparing A+B+A:B vs. the full model is not enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a test of `C`, Type III sum of squares compare the full model with a reduced model where just the main effect of `C` is removed but all interactions involving `C` are retained (see [this excellent post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/21054) for a detailled comparison between the different types of SS). In other words, Type III SS do not respect the [principle of marginality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_marginality).

In order to reproduce the output from `car::Anova` using `anova`, you need to fit the two models first and then feed them into `anova`. The problem is that with only categorical variables (i.e. factors), it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40730731) to drop just the main effect of `C` using the formula interface when interactions with `C` are present in the model. But you can do it by manipulating the model matrix directly (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146368/checking-type-iii-anova-results)). Save the model matrix of the full model and remove the column that corresponds to `C`, then refit the model to obtain the reduced model.

Here is how it's done:

```
library(car)

options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))

#
# The data
#

A <- factor(rep(c("a", "b"), c(4, 8)))
B <- factor(c("x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "x", "x", "x"))
C <- factor(c("l", "l", "m", "m", "l", "l", "m", "m", "l", "l", "l", "l"))
y <- c(14, 30, 15, 35, 50, 51, 30, 32, 51, 55, 53, 55)

dat <- data.frame(y, A, B , C)

m <- lm(y~A*B*C, data = dat)

Anova(m, type = "III")    

Response: y
            Sum Sq Df   F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 9374.5  1 1802.7788 1.839e-06 ***
A            716.0  1  137.6934 0.0003017 ***
B            182.0  1   35.0011 0.0040878 ** 
C            178.0  1   34.2318 0.0042571 ** 
A:B          178.0  1   34.2318 0.0042571 ** 
A:C          317.3  1   61.0267 0.0014491 ** 
B:C            8.5  1    1.6250 0.2714108    
A:B:C          0.0  1    0.0011 0.9754909    
Residuals     20.8  4
```

So far so good. To reproduce the output for `C`, fit the full model, extract the model matrix, remove column corresponding to `C` and refit.

```
m1 <- lm(y~A*B*C, data = dat)  # Full model

X <- model.matrix(m1) # Extract the model matrix of the full model
X0 <- X[, -c(4)] # Removing the column corresponding to C

m0 <- with(dat, lm(y~X0 + 0)) # Reduced model

anova(m0, m1, test = "F")

Model 1: y ~ X0 + 0
Model 2: y ~ A * B * C
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)   
1      5 198.81                                
2      4  20.80  1    178.01 34.232 0.004257 **
```

You see that now we fully reproduced the output from `Anova` for the main effect of `C` using the two models and `anova`.

Comment: Ah! You are awesome! Thank you very much! That's so simple, when I think about it. I missed "connected dots". You showed it perfectly!