# Specifying type of error in 2-way repeated measures ANOVA in R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, anova, repeated-measures

I have a dataset of animal traits with multiple variables that I believe a two way repeated measures anova would be appropriate to analyse the data. Each individual is treated on one side of the body, and untreated for the other side. each individual is reared at either low or high temperature, and the trait values are measured from both sides of the body (paired for treated and untreated), body size for each individual was also measured as a covariate.

I am performing the analysis in R, with the following model:

```
aov = aov(trait ~ bodysize + temperature*treatment + 
                  Error(individual_ID/treatment), df)
```

Based on what I understand, I should use typeIII error, not the default type I error from the `summary()` function. So I tried the Anova() function from the `car` package

However it seems that the data format is not compatible.

```
> Anova(aov, type="III")
Error in UseMethod("vcov") : 
  no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class 
  "c('aovlist', 'listof')"
```

In this case how can I get a proper summary table?

Comment: Type 3 is controversial, so it may be worth considering whether it is appropriate in your case. This answer has a good explanation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/121522

Comment: Also, it's bad practice to give your model a function name (aov).

Comment: Hi, thanks. Since I have an unbalanced design and my main question is to check the interaction between temperature and treatment, so I assume type 3 would be more appropriate...