# Interpretation of summary() and anova() results in R

Tags: regression, mixed-model, interpretation, glmm

I am having some trouble understanding the difference in use of the anova() function and summary() function. For context, here is what I am working on:

I am using GLMMs:

`glmm_dogs2 <- lmer(Den.Weeks ~ Humans * Predators + (1|packseasid), data = dogs)`

`glmm_dogs3 <- lmer(Den.Distance ~ Humans * Predators + (1|packseasid), data = dogs)`

`glmm_dogs4 <- lmer(Pups.lost ~ Humans + Predators + Den.Distance + (1|packseasid), data = dogs)`

The code that I based myself on then continues to plot the residuals and test for normality of residuals, and then goes on to the results, using both `Anova(glmm_dogs2)` and `summary(glmm_dogs2)`. Then I get the following output:

```
Anova(glmm_dogs2) 
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)
Response: Den.Weeks
              Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
Humans           2.1423  1    0.14329  
Predators        5.5678  1    0.01829 *
Humans:Predators 5.0390  1    0.02478 *
-------------
summary(glmm_dogs2)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use
  Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: 
Den.Weeks ~ Humans * Predators + (1 | packseasid)
   Data: dogs

REML criterion at convergence: 98.4

 Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.5586 -0.4267 -0.0769  0.6049  1.6837 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 packseasid (Intercept) 1.015    1.008   
 Residual               2.012    1.419   
Number of obs: 28, groups:  packseasid, 11

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error      df t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          9.9312     0.4444 14.2747  22.347  1.64e-12 ***
Humans1             -2.3783     0.9541 20.1319  -2.493  0.02151 *
Predators1          -3.6509     1.1213 18.7048  -3.256  0.00422 **
Humans1:Predators1   3.9813     1.7736 21.8223   2.245  0.03526 *
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr) Humns1 Prdtr1 
Humans1     -0.255              
Predators1  -0.179  0.126       
Hmns1:Prdt1  0.099 -0.579 -0.673
```

Now I have Chisq and Pr(>Chisq) values, and I have t and Pr(>|t|) values. According to the Anova(), the interaction between Humans:Predators is significant, and Predators is significant, while according to the summary(), all terms including the interaction are significant.
*[Side-note: I already used the `dredge(global_glmm)` function to compace AIC's, so my model has already been reduced, this question mainly pertains to how I should report my results and which variables I can consider to be significantly related to eachother.]*

I did read that the Anova() does a Type II test, and summary() does a type III test, so if I understood it correctly, this means that in this case I should use the summary() output, because of the significant interaction Humans:Predators. However, if the summary() function gave me no significant result, I should use the Anova() results? Or did I misinterpret this?

FYI, below are the results of one of the other GLMM's I constructed, where there is no significant interaction; in this case I would then use the Anova() results in my report because the summary() didn't show any significant interactions?

```
Anova(glmm_dogs3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)
Response: Den.Distance
          Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
Humans           3.4109  1    0.06477 .
Predators        0.0976  1    0.75467  
Humans:Predators 1.3987  1    0.23694  
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> summary(glmm_dogs3)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use
Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: 
Den.Distance ~ Humans * Predators + (1 | packseasid)
  Data: dogs

REML criterion at convergence: 108.9

Scaled residuals: 
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.28514 -0.50117 -0.01259  0.56893  2.10258 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 packseasid (Intercept) 2.554    1.598   
 Residual               2.652    1.628   
Number of obs: 28, groups:  packseasid, 11

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate  Std. Error    df    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          2.1269     0.6105 11.2745   3.484   0.00494 **
Humans1              0.9035     1.1232 17.1159   0.804   0.43221  
Predators1          -0.7322     1.3067 15.6333  -0.560   0.58319
Humans1:Predators1   2.4991     2.1131 18.7481   1.183   0.25172
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr) Humns1 Prdtr1
Humans1     -0.211     
Predators1  -0.143  0.132       
Hmns1:Prdt1  0.071 -0.586 -0.670
```

Comment: Which type of sum of squares you should use depends on what you want to find out.  See  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20452/how-to-interpret-type-i-type-ii-and-type-iii-anova-and-manova