What exactely is "the part of the interaction orthogonal to factors $A$ and $B$" in a two-way ANOVA?
Consider a two-way ANOVA with factors $A$ and $B$ and the interaction $A\times B$.
The author of this answer answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/608301/359647 (@svendvn) explains that the Type III sum of squares for factor $A$ is computed by considering the model $y \sim B + o(A,B)$, where $o(A,B)$ is the part of the interaction orthogonal to factors $A$ and $B$. For those of you who are not familiar with this notation, $y \sim B + o(A,B)$ translates to $$y = \mu + \langle \boldsymbol\delta,\boldsymbol b\rangle + \langle \boldsymbol\beta, \boldsymbol z\rangle + \epsilon,$$ where $\mu$ is the global intercept, $\boldsymbol\delta$ is a vector of the effects of $B$'s factor levels (excluding the reference category), $\boldsymbol\beta$ are the effects of the "orthogonal part", $\boldsymbol z$ is the "orthogonal part", and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the usual Euclidean inner product. For example, if $B$ was a factor with two factor levels, $\langle\boldsymbol\delta,\boldsymbol b\rangle = \beta_1\cdot b_1$ with $b_1$ being a dummy variable that is equal to one for the second factor level and equal to zero for the first factor level.
Why question is: how is $o(A,B)$ and $\boldsymbol z$ are defined, respectively?
My thoughts: So far I assumed dummy coding. For simplicity, let's switch to effect coding, and let's assume that we are given a balanced design, i.e., the sample size for each factor level combination is identical. Then we have that the underlying design matrix is orthogonal (i.e., the crossproduct is a diagonal matrix). In that case, the interaction is, by construction, orthogonal to both factors. Would that correspond to $o(A,B) = A\times B$? And what if the above assumption made for simplification do not hold?

I don't find that language useful at all; I had an answer here but have moved it to the original question, as it fits better there. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/654449/3601.
