# Question on statistical significance in single vs multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, p-value

So I was volunteering on a research project and the main researcher would often talk about how an independent variable could be statistically insignificant in a single linear regression but it could be significant if included with other variables in multiple linear regression or visa versa. I was really confused by this concept but unfortunately he did not have time to explain it to me. I was wondering if anyone on hear could explain this in a clear and simple way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples illustrating two *non-exhaustive* but hopefully still instructive situations.

**Example #1**

We simulate a dataset with two continuous predictors, *x1* and *x2*, and a continuous response *y* so that on its own *x2* is "not significant" in a single linear regression of *y* on *x2* but it is "significant" in a multiple linear regression of *y* on both *x1* and *x2*.

Both predictors are linearly associated with *y* because *x1* and *x2* separately "cause" *y* without interacting with each other. However, most of the variation in *y* is explained by *x1* and only a little of the variation in *y* is explained by *x2*. If we don't include *x1* in the regression the residual variation is very high and the *x2* coefficient doesn't reach significance.

Lesson learned: Even if we are primarily interested in studying the relationship between a particular predictor *x2* and the outcome *y*, it's helpful to adjust the analysis for known covariates, esp. if these covariates explain a lot of the observed variability of *y*.

[image]

```r
anova(lm(y ~ x2, data = sim))
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#> 
#> Response: y
#>           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
#> x2         1   22.59  22.594  0.8305 0.3644
#> Residuals 98 2666.09  27.205

anova(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = sim))
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#> 
#> Response: y
#>           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
#> x1         1 2562.36 2562.36 2766.744 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> x2         1   36.48   36.48   39.394 9.723e-09 ***
#> Residuals 97   89.83    0.93
```

The same phenomenon explained with lots more words: [How can adding a 2nd IV make the 1st IV significant?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28474/how-can-adding-a-2nd-iv-make-the-1st-iv-significant)

**Example #2**

We simulate a dataset with two continuous predictors, *x1* and *x2*, and a continuous response *y* so that on its own *x2* is "significant" in a single linear regression of *y* on *x2* but it is "not significant" in a multiple linear regression of *y* on both *x1* and *x2*.

Both predictors are linearly associated with *y* because *x1* and *x2* are correlated with a third *latent* variable *x0* which generates *y* "behind the scenes". The correlation between *x2* and *x0* is weaker than the correlation between *x1* and *x0*, so once we include *x1* in the regression, there is no systematic variability left for *x2* to explain.

Lesson learned: Association is not causation. Even the simplest of simulations illustrates that regression tells us only about the associations between the known predictors and the response, not about the true data generating process.

[image]

```r
anova(lm(y ~ x2, data = sim))
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#> 
#> Response: y
#>           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
#> x2         1 124.27 124.273  106.47 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> Residuals 98 114.39   1.167                      

anova(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = sim))
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#> 
#> Response: y
#>           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value Pr(>F)    
#> x1         1 133.899 133.899 123.9919 <2e-16 ***
#> x2         1   0.012   0.012   0.0116 0.9146    
#> Residuals 97 104.750   1.080
```

The R code in all its gory details:

```r
library("broom")
library("ggeffects")
library("tidyverse")
library("patchwork")


# Example 1

set.seed(1234)

n <- 100

sim <- tibble(
  x1 = rnorm(n, sd = 1),
  x2 = rnorm(n, sd = 2),
  noise = rnorm(n),
  y = 5 * x1 + 0.25 * x2 + noise
)

m.2 <- lm(y ~ x2, data = sim)
m12 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = sim)

anova(m.2)
anova(m12)

p.2 <- ggpredict(m.2, terms = c("x2")) %>% plot()
p.2 <- p.2 + ggtitle("Predicted values of y given x2")
p12 <- ggpredict(m12, terms = c("x2", "x1 [-2,0,2]")) %>% plot()
p12 <- p12 + ggtitle("Predicted values of y given x1 and x2")

p.2 + p12


# Example #2

set.seed(1234)

n <- 100

sim <- tibble(
  x0 = rnorm(n, sd = 1),
  x1 = x0 + rnorm(n, sd = 0.1),
  x2 = x0 + rnorm(n, sd = 0.3),
  noise = rnorm(n),
  y = x0 + noise
)

m.2 <- lm(y ~ x2, data = sim)
m12 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = sim)

anova(m.2)
anova(m12)

p.2 <- ggpredict(m.2, terms = c("x2")) %>% plot()
p.2 <- p.2 + ggtitle("Predicted values of y given x2")
p12 <- ggpredict(m12, terms = c("x2", "x1 [-2,0,2]")) %>% plot()
p12 <- p12 + ggtitle("Predicted values of y given x1 and x2")

p.2 + p12
```